# QSplitter и QMdiArea подгонка размера

Tags: qt, qt4

```
В mainwindow:
QWidget* central = new QWidget;
setCentralWidget(central);
splitter = new QSplitter(Qt::Vertical);
QVBoxLayout* vbl = new QVBoxLayout( central );
QMdiArea* mdiArea = new QMdiArea;
splitter->addWidget( mdiArea );
QWidget* w = new QWidget; 
...
splitter->addWidget( w );
```

Т.е. вверху mdi area, внизу второй виджет.
При изменении содержимого / ресайзе mdiSubWindow в mdiArea это окно может частично оказываться под нижним виджетом w. Как это можно исправить? Т.е. чтобы QSplitter и QMdiArea подстраивали свой размер под содержимое. Сейчас учитывается только минимальный заданный размер mdiSubWindow, т.е. при перемещении сплиттера видимая в нем область mdiArea не становится меньше этих размеров. Но остальная часть mdiArea может быть скрыта под виджетом w.

Вот тестовый пример, который работает таким же образом:

test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <qwidget.h>

#include "ui_test.h"

namespace Ui
{
  class Test;
}
class Test : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    Test();
    ~Test(){}
    private:
    Ui::Test* ui_;
};

#endif
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <qapplication.h>

#include "test.h"
#include <ui_test.h>

Test::Test()
  :QMainWindow(),
   ui_( new Ui::Test )
{
  ui_->setupUi(this);
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  QApplication app( argc, argv );
  Test* t = new Test;
  app.setActiveWindow(t);
  t->show();
  app.exec();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

test.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Test</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="Test">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>699</width>
    <height>643</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_4">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QMdiArea" name="mdiArea">
       <widget class="QWidget" name="subwindow">
        <property name="windowTitle">
         <string>Дочернее окно</string>
        </property>
        <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
         <item row="0" column="0">
          <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>500</width>
             <height>500</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="currentIndex">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>500</width>
              <height>500</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <attribute name="title">
             <string>Tab 1</string>
            </attribute>
            <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
             <item row="0" column="0">
              <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit"/>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
           <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>500</width>
              <height>500</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <attribute name="title">
             <string>Tab 2</string>
            </attribute>
            <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
             <item row="0" column="0">
              <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
               <property name="text">
                <string>TextLabel</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="1" column="0">
              <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
               <property name="orientation">
                <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
               </property>
               <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
                <size>
                 <width>20</width>
                 <height>40</height>
                </size>
               </property>
              </spacer>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_5">
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
        </item>
        <item row="1" column="0">
         <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox"/>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>699</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

При предпросмотре в дизайнере формы она работает аналогично - при перемещении вверх сплиттера, если mdiSubWindow больше минимального размера, часть mdiSubWindow скрывается под нижним виджетом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша задача несколько противоречит общепринятому поведению обозначенных типов виджетов. `QMdiArea` как раз и создана для того, чтобы в ограниченной своими размерами визуальной области предоставлять доступ к дочерним окнам максимально комфортно посредством использования полос прокруток.

Когда же в приоритет ставится размер `QMdiSubWindow`, то `QMdiArea` фактически теряет своё функциональное назначение, превращаясь в обычный виджет. Но мало того, Вам придётся написать самостоятельно обработчики событий ресайза как для `QMdiArea`, так и для `QSplitter`.

В этих кастомных обработчиках событий потребуется учитывать также и то, что `QMdiArea` может содержать не одно дочернее окно, а несколько, что фактически приведёт к необходимости учёта местоположения каждого дочернего окна с тем, чтобы по самому низлежащему определять, насколько `QSplitter` может приподняться к верхнему краю окна.

Вероятно лучше пересмотреть такой подход к построению виджетов в сторону иной стратегии. В конце концов, если уж обязательно нужен `QMdiArea`, то он может работать и в стиле `QTabWidget`:

```
QMdiArea *area = new QMdiArea(this);
area->setViewMode(QMdiArea::TabbedView);
```

В этом случае размер дочерних "окон" будет автоматически подстраиваться с учётом положения `QSplitter`.